# Intellij idea default setting for projects

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, default, new-project

My code style settings keep getting reset when I create a new project, and I have to re-export from the default ide configurations.

is it possible to make some factory settings for the project (code style for java, general code style, optimize imports on the fly setting) so that when creating a project they are as I specified them in advance and not set everything up again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File | New Projects Setup | Settings for New Projects...

Comment: But how can I set it so that the "optimize imports on the fly" function does not turn off, or at least works in new projects?

Comment: Please [vote for this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237002/Optimize-imports-on-the-fly-allow-to-make-it-a-default-setting-for-new-projects).